# На каждые 10 добавлений в список печаталось Hello world

Tags: python, list, список, append

Помогите решить задачу.На каждые 10 добавлений в список например печаталось Hello world.

```py
y = []
for x in range(100):
    y.append(x)

print(y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y = []

for x in range(100):
    y.append(x)
    if not x % 10 and x:
        print("{} Hello world".format(x))
```